# Why is my MFC project trying to link to .NET/using managed services?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc

I'm trying to understand why my most recent mfc-project is trying to use .NET and manage dservices.
This project compiles and executes well but I get some strange warnings and messages in the output:

```
c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\system.core.dll : 
warning C4945: 'ExtensionAttribute' : 
cannot import symbol from 'c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\system.core.dll': 
as 'System::Runtime::CompilerServices::ExtensionAttribute' 
has already been imported from another assembly 'mscorlib'
```

and

```
'myProject.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): 
Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'
```

I've made a few mfc-projects so far and none of them has this messages. The project settings are the same, I reviewed them twice. Of course I don't use any manged techniques knowingly. It goes without saying I know little to nothing about managed coding. ;-)

Can anybody tell me why my project is trying to use .NET and how cant I preven it from doing it?

Comment: This is a serious problem that you need to fix, your project is being compiled with the wrong mscorlib.dll reference assembly.  Not fixing it will cause your program to bomb with an inscrutable error message when you run it on a machine that only has .NET 4.0 installed.  It can only work on a machine that has 4.5 or higher.  You have a dependency on .NET because one or more of your source code files is compiled with /clr in effect.  Bit of a mess, really, you'll have to unravel it yourself.  Look at the General settings page for each source code file.

Comment: Thank you, Hans.
There was a single source file with its 'Common Langue RunTime Support' set in the C/C++ general settings.